# Access data after persistance

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot, JpaRepository to save entity into database.

```
School createdSchool =  schoolRepository.save(school);
```

after this if I do

```
createdSchool.getId();
```

It returns me null. How to get full object after persisting the data.

Comment: need to `refresh` your entity

Comment: normally this should work. Can you show more of your code, please.

Comment: which is null? the return value of the createdSchool.getId() or the createdSchool itself?

Answer (score -1):

save()method returns list. Take a look here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

Comment: `JpaRepository` includes `CrudRepository` which returns a single object.